# How to call parent method from Modal

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

Is it possible somehow to call method of controller that called modal?

Basically I have HomePage in which I called UserInfoModal. Can I somehow call HomePage.changeStatus from UserInfoModal?

Parent:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'HomePage .html',
})

export class HomePage {
   ...
   createModal() {
      let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(UserInfoModal, item, 
                                         this.supervisor);
      myModal.present();
   }

   changeStatus(item) {
      ...
   }
}
```

Modal:

```
@Component({
   templateUrl: 'UserInfoModal.html',
   selector: 'userinfo-modal'
})

export class UserInfoModal{
   ...
   changeParentStatus() {
      // call 'changeStatus()' from parent
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code please?

Comment: you can do that in the constructor of the modal  class when you load the modal

Comment: Maybe you can pass the function to the modal?

Comment: here with the code example

Answer (score 9):

@JeffHuijsmans is correct in the comment. You can pass the function as a parameter using `NavParams` and call it.

```
@Component({
   selector: 'page-home',
   templateUrl: 'HomePage .html',
})

    export class HomePage {
       ...
       createModal() {
          let myModal = this.modalCtrl.create(UserInfoModal, {item: item, 
                                             supervisor: this.supervisor,change:this.changeStatus.bind(this)});
          myModal.present();
       }

       changeStatus(item) {
          ...
       }
    }
```

In the modal,

```
export class UserInfoModal{
    changeStatus:any;
   constructor(private navParams:NavParams){
     this.changeStatus =  this.navParams.get("change");
   }
   ...
   changeParentStatus() {
      this.changeStatus();
   }
}
```